# Array render objects by several items, not only one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I render in one container several object? For example I have array

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
array.map((item, index) => (
<div>
 <div> item 1, 2, 3 </div>
 <div> item 4, 5, 6 </div>
 <div> item 7, 8, 9 </div>
</div
)
```

Comment: Yes. You can do that.

Comment: What should your expected output look like

Comment: You can do this, you just have to decompose to subcomponents and assemble you "master component" with them.

Comment: Your question might not be a dupe to the linked question, but you'll still find the answer you want there. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#slice` to split your array then use `array#map` to display one chunk at a time.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var Div = () => {
  return(
    <div>
    {array
    .map((item, index, array) => 
      index % 3 === 0 ? array.slice(index, index+3) : null)
    .filter(x => x)
    .map((item, index) => (<div>item {item.join(', ')}</div>))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Div />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
```